# codeinighter where field = data from form

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to match up suppliers from a postcode search:

**Model code:**

```
function get_suppliers(){
    $this->db->from('suppliers');
    $this->db->where('postcode', $data);
    $this->db->select('name,type,site,contact,number');

    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function index()
{
$this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('postcode','Postcode', 'required|numeric|exact_length[4]');
    $data = array(
        'postcode' => $this->input->post('postcode')
                );
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        ## reload page ##
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    else
    {
    $this->load->model('site_model');

    $this->site_model->add_record($data);   

    echo("postcode entered");   

    $data['rows'] = $this->site_model->get_suppliers($data);
    print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Obviously ignore the printers and echo thats just me bring to see whats going on I'm pretty sure i need to just change the $data in model to something just not sure what(tried heaps of things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model:**

```
function get_suppliers($postcode = '*') // <-- Capture the postcode
{
    $this->db->from('suppliers');
    $this->db->where('postcode', $postcode); // <-- pass it in here
    $this->db->select('name,type,site,contact,number');

    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('postcode','Postcode', 'required|numeric|exact_length[4]');

    $data = array(
        'postcode' => $this->input->post('postcode')
    );

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        ## reload page ##
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('site_model');

        $this->site_model->add_record($data);   

        $data['rows'] = $this->site_model->get_suppliers( $data['postcode'] ); // <-- pass the postcode

        echo("postcode entered: " . $data['postcode'] . "<pre>");
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps i don't think i would have ever thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
function get_suppliers($data = ''){
```

i.e.: You haven't included `$data` as the argument

Comment: thanks heaps but how do i specifically target postcode not the $data array i can't just set data equal to something the postcode is coming from a form. coming from a form.

Comment: When you're calling the `$data` as an argument for the function `get_suppliers`, the variable `$data` is the one you're passing in your controller. The scope of this `$data` variable is only within this function, and the score of your `$data` array is only within the controller. :)

Comment: As for passing the post code into the function, you can use a form and pass the posted data (you'll be asking for a postcode) or the `$_GET` data to pass the post code into the function.